# Particle Board Procedural Texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, displacement, procedural, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a particle board type texture procedurally for 3d printing and am wondering how to go about it. I attempted to make it with displacement but it turned out too lumpy. Thank you so much! [image]

Comment: Particle board is layered in just 1 dimension .. is a procedural texture in UV space OK? (Can your objects be UV mapped?)

Comment: I'm trying to add the texture to a flat surface that is to be 3D printed so yes I believe?

Comment: that's a yes. A 2D texture will be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shot at a procedural particle board, that can be baked to an image for the purposes of modifier *Displacement*:

[image]

As you can see, it's a bit big to be simply illustrated. It divides the UV space into Voronoi cells. Each cell sets the rotation of the UV space about its own center, and fills it with a composite of directed noises and a triangle *Wave* texture, for a mix of:

- A very regular *Wave*, wobbled slightly, so not completely straight
- A stretched Musgrave, for harsh fine grain
- Another Musgrave, and Voronoi Distance From Edge, to put in some speckles and directed trenches.

[image]

(The above texture is 1K, you could run it as a test before committing..)

This sort of thing can be tweaked for ever.. I've tried to label up the branches so you can adjust them, dispense with them altogether, or replace them with other ideas. For example, it looks as though the trenches could be enlarged / reshaped ..

The result so far is:

[image]

It's probably easier to shoot an emissive version of the texture on a plane, through an Ortho camera, than to use the baking mechanism.. the attached .blend is set up for that.

Because the texture is periodic, there will be some Moiré interference with a (periodic) subdivision of your surface, and/or banding from your printer, you might choose some dense random triangulation of the surface, to avoid at least, the first of those.

[image]